# How to put a member profile link into embed author url? - discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm fetching some infos via a modal from new members on our discord.. On Submission the bot posts the user inputs as an embed. It looks like this: [Embed looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SYvw.jpg)

Usually one of the admins needs to DM the new member so it would be nice if the new users profile could be attached to the embed. Ideally it would open the users profile as a pop up, like it does when you click on a users name in a channel.. : [I want this open when you click on the embed author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyIXm.jpg)

The problem is that you cant fetch a users profile url (at least I can't find it in the discord.py documentation)
So I tried to build the profile links like this:

```
profurl = 'https://discord.com/users/' + str(interaction.user.id)
embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Anmeldung - {ligatitle}      \n\u200b', color=discord.Color.random())
embed.set_author(name=interaction.user, url=profurl, icon_url=auticon)
```

It sort of works, but the problem is that it opens the users profile in the browser, instead of the discord app. If I click the link from mobile phone discord app it does exactly what I want, it just somehow doesn't work on the PC App.

Anyone got an idea? It's not mandatory for me to open users Profile, I just need a way that admins can DM the new user with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
profurl = 'discord://-/users/' + str(interaction.user.id)
```

This simply uses the Discord protocol that is registered in your system to redirect to the application instead of HTTP.

Comment: 'discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embeds.0.author.url: Scheme "discord" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ("http", "https").'

this does not work since the url attribute needs an http or https format.

if I put an https in front it obviously does not work either:

'discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embeds.0.author.url: Not a well formed URL.'

Answer (score 0):

So I did a little workaround, if ever anyone runs into a similar problem:

[my workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3oQH.jpg)

I just added another field to the embed, where I mentioned the interaction user. If you click on it it opens the users profile in a popup and you can DM him right away.

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Anmeldung - {ligatitle}   \n\u200b', color=discord.Color.random())
embed.set_author(name=interaction.user, icon_url=auticon)
embed.set_thumbnail(url=auticon)
embed.add_field(name='DC Name:', value=interaction.user.mention, inline=False)
```